# Reflection:get Object state from return type of method in runtime

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aspectj

Have annotated Java class with several methods:

```
@CustomAnnotation
public class MyService {

public List<MyObject> getMyObjects(){
...
}

public SomeObject getSomeObject(){
...
}

}
```

I should to log field values of `MyObject` and `SomeObject` instances.

`aspectj` part,where `MyService` object got:

```
public void logg2(JoinPoint jp) {
    Object target = jp.getTarget();
```

}

`target` is  `MyService` class,that holds methods.

How to get values of instance fields for `MyObject` and `SomeObject`,that are returned from methods in `MyService` class in Runtime?

Comment: What do you mean by the "state"? Do you mean all instance variables etc..? If you tell us what you're trying to get more precisely we might be able to suggest something :-)

Comment: edited. exactly, state  means values of instance fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Around(value = "traceReturnedObjectsFields()")
public Object traceAnotherOne(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
    Object res = null;
    res = jp.proceed();
    if (res == null)
        return res;
    Class<?> c1 = res.getClass();
    Field[] fields = c1.getDeclaredFields();
    AccessibleObject.setAccessible(fields, true);
    for (Field field : fields) {
        if (!Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())) {
            System.out.println(field + " = " + field.get(res));
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: alehro,in this case your method returns fields for current object(that is my Service class),and I need get objects,that are returned from methods OF Service class,not Service class fields itself

Comment: "I need get objects,that are returned from methods OF Service class,not Service class fields itself". - that's exactly what it does. Have you tried the code? Have you read that or understood? I bet you didn't. Should I publish the whole testing project with self explaining names, logging and so on? Sorry for the offensive tone, but being down-voted for the correct and tested answer is really strange.

Comment: @sergionni To be sure that you are on the right way, answer for yourself on following questions: 1. How works around advice? 2. What will return jp.proceed() if the apect will be adapted and applied to your case?

Comment: hi,thank you for comments.Feel idiot myself)).Tested,your sample is absolutely working and matches my case.I'll revert vote as soon it will be possible.Thank you for help.

Comment: @sergionni That's all right. I've edited my answer. Probably now you can revert the voting.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object target = jp.getTarget();
for (Class<?> superclass = target.getClass();
     superclass != Object.class;
     superclass = superclass.getSuperclass())
{
   Field[] fields = superclass.getDeclaredFields();
   AccessibleObject.setAccessible(fields, true);
   for (Field field : fields)
   {
      if (!Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers()))
      {
         System.out.println(field + " = " + field.get(target));
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: looks like .getSuperClass() doesn't match for my case.It's needed for classes,that are returned by methods.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the question, and the update doesn't help me understand what you want.  Perhaps give full example classes and desired output.

Comment: in two words: i need to get values of objects,that are returned from methods.And I know about object,that holds these methods only.See ,please,code.

Comment: Having recently had to deal with reflection a lot, especially checking fields of superclasses, thanks for posting that for loop- I'd never thought of using one like that!

Comment: @sergionni Unless there's some other metadata, there's no way to "know" which field will be returned by a method.  Do you want to match the field based on the method return type, do you want to call the methods using reflection, or do you want to do something else?